# AngularJS filter array and display property of first object in Angular view

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am trying something like this.

```
<select  data-ng-model="modelName" 
    data-ng-options="item.id as (item.id + ' - ' +item.name) for item in options">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
</select>
{{options | filter:modelName}}
```

options are an array of object. The object structure is {id:XYZ, name:ABC}. So array is

```
[{id:XYZ, name:ABC},{id:XYZ1, name:ABC1},{id:XYZ2, name:ABC2}]
```

For above code my output is being

> {id:XYZ, name:ABC}

But I want only '**ABC**'

**Note:** 
I know that I can use custom filter for it. But is there any better approach? Certainly for this small thing I do not want to create any directive also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just wrap the entire angular expression with a bracket and access the first item's `name` property.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/tCdnbAxwWoo445PaMoA6?p=preview)**

```
{{ (options | filter:modelName)[0].name }}
```

Comment: Superb! I tried this but I did not add [0] (index) there. My Bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngInit:

```
<span ng-init = "model = (options | filter:modelName)[0]">{{model.name}}</span>
```